# vue check value in textfield

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i want to check value in input if has any value in input i want to add class **sh-is-active** to a div using **VUE** but i don't know how... please help me

```
<template>
   <div class="sh-wrap sh-wrap-input sh-is-active">
      <label class="sh-label">First and Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="sh-form-control sh-input" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
      <span for="email" class="error">Required</span>
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: what you probably want to do is set up the input with a v-model, and then set up a Vue watch on that model which changes the class array of the div.

Comment: what you probably want to do is set up the input with a v-model, and then set up a Vue watch on that model which changes the class array of the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `v-model` bind a value to the input and to dynamically add the classes `:class="{ 'sh-is-active': name }"`. Read the [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) on how to bind classes and styles

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',

  data() {
    return {
      name: null
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.sh-wrap-input {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.sh-is-active {
  background: yellow;
}

.sh-label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .125rem;
}

.error {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: .125rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="example" class="sh-wrap sh-wrap-input" :class="{ 'sh-is-active': name }">
  <label class="sh-label">First and Last Name</label>
  <input v-model="name" type="text" class="sh-form-control sh-input" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
  <span v-if="!name" for="email" class="error">Required</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dota2Match glad it worked. If you want more information you can read the docs from the link I mentioned and I also added a working example. Please make sure you accepted the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

to check if value exists you can add `:value="inputValue"`
and watch for it using

```
watch: {inputValue: function(value){
"add your class here" 

}}
```